# Уже существующий, но еще мало изученный(,) вид экономического предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую, которая находится в скобках? И есть ли конкретное правило по подобным конструкциям?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как выглядит [полное предложение](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD_%D0%94_%D0%91_%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%94_%D0%A5_%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83_%D0%B2/1).
**Так что же в этом нового? А вот что: впечатления, которые представляют собой уже существующий, но еще мало изученный вид экономического предложения.**

Сочинительный союз **но** в этом предложении служит для связи определений:
вид (какой?) существующий, но [еще мало] изученный.

Обычно обособляются уточняющие определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста:
*Ещё одно,* (какое именно?) *последнее, сказанье — и летопись окончена моя* (Пушкин);
*Кой-где выглянули женские,* (какие именно?) *большей частью старушечьи, головы* (Тургенев).

Думаю, что все правильно: запятая нужна только перед «но» (между однородными определениями), так как явно выраженного уточнения нет — ни по интонации, ни по смыслу.

[Уточняющие члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Ответ меня немного удивил. Автор вопроса интересуется правилом постановки запятой между однородными членами при наличии союза НО. Вы это правило не приводите,  но в то же время подробно разбираете тему уточняющих членов, говорите, что нет явного уточнения. Но разве может  вообще обособляться (в качестве уточняющего) определение  с союзом НО?

Comment: И еще у меня вопрос по ссылкам. По-моему лучше давать ссылки на Розенталя, чем на пересказ этого же материала на других сайтах, да еще с рекламой. Я таким пересказам не очень доверяю. Что в них может быть нового, а вот субъективное  и непроверенное вполне может быть.

Comment: 1. Конечно, Розенталь — это наше всё. Но ведь Вы своем ответе уже привели ссылку — чего ж повторяться? 2. Я представила это предложение с инверсией: _...уже существующий, **но еще изученный мало,** вид экономического предложения. Мне показалось, что в этом случае возможна указанная — "уточнительная" — запятая.

Comment: Римма, а у вас есть примеры предложений, в которых уточняющий член включает союз НО?  Я что-то плохо представляю такой вариант. Например, союз А ТАКЖЕ может  быть соединительным и присоединительным, а насчет НО у меня есть сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

*...уже **существующий**, **но** еще мало **изученный**  вид экономического предложения.*

Запятая ставится перед противительным союзом НО, соединяющим однородные (распространенные) определения.

Правило: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

5. **Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством противительных союзов** а, но, да (в значении ‘но’), однако, зато и др., подчинительных союзов (уступительных, условных) хотя, если, пусть,ставится запятая: Теперь море сияло уже не сплошь, а лишь в нескольких местах (Кат.); Было светло, но по-осеннему скучно (М. Г.); На взгляд-то, он хорош, да зелен (Кр); Дни стояли пасмурные, однако тёплые (Акс.); Приют наш мал, зато спокоен (Л.); Вопрос спорный, тем не менее важный, **Да, это был прекрасный, хотя и несколько печальный город** (Пауст.); Случай исключительный, если не единственный в своём роде.